# which logger can be used with php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

which logger can be used with php codeigniter? any suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to functionality used for writing log messages, CodeIgniter comes with a very simple [`log_message()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) function for you to use. Building a class to take advantage of that function (and possibly related functions) should be quite easy.